# Auto redirect to different web page

Tags: redirect

I am trying to create example.com/abc page for my site but I am getting permalink as example.com/abc-3. When I am entering example.com/abc it is redirecting me to example.com//wp-content/uploads/2018/09/on-page-seo.png

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a permalink that is `abc-3` while you are entering `abc` that often suggests that somewhere the slug is already being used. Perhaps `abc` is already used as a category, or a page. Or perhaps it was previously created and deleted and it is still in the trash. Make sure you delete it even from the trash so that that slug can be re-used.

Comment: I will try this, can you answer why is that auto redirection happening when I hit the URL example.com/pagename it is redirecting to example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/on-page-seo.png

Comment: Also, I have that abc as a category, should I first delete the category and try building the page again?

Comment: query is resolved

Comment: If the suggestions have helped, please click on the green gray checkmark or the uptick.